# How to add annotations to captured variables or delegated objects in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, delegates

I want to dynamically implement an interface by extending an existing class as an anonymous object.
This anonymous object captures a method parameter to implement the interface method:

```
fun myFunc(someObj: SomeObj, update: Boolean) = object : SomeObj(/*copy some values from someObj*/), SomeInterface {
   override fun doUpdate() = update
}
```

This implementation captures the `update` method parameter and adds it as a synthetic `$update` field into the anonymous object. I need to annotate this field as my serialization framework includes the `$update` field when its not marked as `@Transient`.

Another approach by delegation suffers from the same issue:

```
fun myFunc(someObj: SomeObj, update: Boolean) {
   val someInterfaceImpl = object : SomeInterface {
      override fun doUpdate() = update
   }
   return object : SomeObj(/*copy some values from someObj*/), SomeInterface by someInterfaceImpl 
}
```

I cannnot annotate `someInterfaceImpl` in any place with `@delegate:Transient` or `@Transient`.
In essence:

- Is there a way to annotate captured variables in Kotlin?
- Is there a way to annotate the field when delegating to an object?

I am required to do this by annotations as the framework does not offer any other way to exclude fields, not even by names.

Furthermore I am not talking about delegated properties but delegated interfaces.

Comment: Are you aware that you can just declare a named class and create an instance of that class instead, rather than an object literal? Then you can annotate whatever field you like in that class.

Comment: I am not accustomed to Kotlin yet and made a few syntax errors, thank you for noting - it should be fine and more clear now.

I am aware that I can declare a named class, but `SomeObj` has like 12 immutable fields and its a lot of copy paste because I would have to forward the 12 parameters. I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: The anonymous object only passes values directly to `SomeObj`, there is no forwarding here, the named class would need the same value passing + forwarding in it's class & constructor definition.

But this is very pedantic, your solution is valid - I am just looking for a way to avoid 50-70 lines of boilerplate and a class with 12 arguments is usually formatted with each arguments on a new line (to make max line limits happy) which would make the forwarding named class take >= 24 lines which isn't saving on the boilerplate :)

Comment: That being said I am still interested if there is another solution to this, it seems odd that the delegation language feature is this limiting in regards to annotations :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you got my point. Have you considered making the named class' constructor take only 2 parameters - an instance of `SomeObj` and an `updated`, rather than all 12 parameters of `SomeObj`'s constructor?

Comment: To be honest, I think delegation is going in the wrong direction here. The problem here is you want to add annotations to things captured in an object literal. Delegation is not intended to solve that problem. The problem has a very simple solution - make a named class. I still fail to see how this would cause more copy-paste than your existing `myFunc` implementation would.

Comment: I have oversimplified the example so your take is correct. In reality `SomeObj` is converted to another, similiar class `SomeOtherObj` so the already present transformation code cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a named class:

```
fun myFunc(someObj: SomeObj, update: Boolean): SomeObj {
    class SomeObjSubclass(someObj: SomeObj, @Transient val update: Boolean):
        SomeObj(someObj.prop1, someObj.prop2, /* and so on*/), SomeInterface {
        override fun doUpdate() = update
    }
    return SomeObjSubclass(someObj, update)
}
```

Notice that `myFunc` is now merely a wrapper for `SomeObj`. Depending on your design, you could just make `myFunc` the `SomeObj` subclass instead:

```
class MyFunc(someObj: SomeObj, @Transient val update: Boolean):
        SomeObj(someObj.prop1, someObj.prop2, /* and so on*/), SomeInterface {
    override fun doUpdate() = update
}
```

Callers would call `MyFunc(...)` as if it were a function, and they would receive something assignable to `SomeObj`, just like before.

You can also add a secondary constructor to `SomeObj` that takes a `SomeObj`, and copy the properties there

```
constructor(someObj: SomeObj): this(
    someObj.prop1, someObj.prop2, /* and so on */
)
```

Then the declaration of `MyFunc` can just be:

```
class MyFunc(someObj: SomeObj, @Transient val update: Boolean):
        SomeObj(someObj), SomeInterface {
    override fun doUpdate() = update
}
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as it's a good solution for other people having a similar question to mine ! :)